# Using "it" as a verb object

Tags: grammar

Can I use "it" as a verb object  ?

I enjoy it that I go to Chicago.

I do not mind it that you smoke at my room.

Comment: Both examples sound a little awkward to me, but the first one much more than the second.

Comment: I mean that  "I do not mind that you smoke at my room."  is not grammatical.

Comment: You should use "in my room" rather than "at my room," but removing the **it** results in a perfectly grammatical sentence.

Comment: The sentences take one object, which is either **it** or some other noun phrase.  They can't take two objects.

Answer (score 2):

Certain verbs: enjoy, like, dislike, hate, fear, take ING or you can use those verbs followed by it with a clause: like it when etc. love it when etc. hate it that, etc.

- I enjoy **going** to Chicago.
- I enjoy **it** when I go to Chicago. [it, the fact I go to Chicago]

Also:

- He likes playing tennis. [Also: He likes to play tennis]
- He likes **it** that you play tennis. it= the fact

However, "I enjoy it that"  is a bit awkward.

He enjoys making his mother laugh.
He enjoys that his mother laughs when he make jokes.

If you use it after enjoy, you need to a clause because the it refers to that clause.

They like **it** when the children come to dinner. [it= the children coming to dinner]

Answer (score 1):

The word "it" is a pronoun. You can use pronouns in the same way that you use nouns, including as the object of a sentence. However, they are *replacements* for nouns - you shouldn't use them both. In your first example, "it" means the same thing as "that I go to Chicago," so you should choose one or the other.

This is incorrect:

> I enjoy it that I go to Chicago.

This is correct:

> I enjoy that I go to Chicago.

If it is clear from context that the "it" you are talking about is "that I go to Chicago," this is also correct:

> I enjoy it.

Comment: I thought that object for "enjoy" must be noun or noun form , but not the "that" construction.

Comment: @Marek "that I go to Chicago" is a noun phrase, which can be used as an object. It works the same way as the gerund form "going to Chicago," which is probably more common.

Comment: @Marek and MJD, "that I go to Chicago" is never a Noun Phrase. It is a clause; in your example sentence it is a subordinate clause introduced by a subordinator *that*. Whether there will be a Gerund-Participle clause or a subordinate clause is decided by the verb *enjoy*, and those constituents are called complement. As far as I know *enjoy* does not license a subordinate clause as complement, even if it does it is very rare so *I enjoy that I go to Chicago* is not in very common usage. It is very conversational I guess.